# AWS Lambda is not loading CSS due to some reasons

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a small PHP application. My application has only two files:

1. index.php
2. style.css

I zipped both files and uploaded to lambda. I used a PHP layer to execute PHP on lambda.

PHP, is running fine and i got the expected result but the css is not loading.

In the network tab of console *I saw 403 error*.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda is a compute layer. You wouldn't want it to serve up CSS. CSS file needs to go in S3 bucket and served from there.

could a Lambda return css? sure.

Think about it this way, the URL in your post. when invoked, it will launch a lambda. The lambda will process index.php and return html. the css would have to be part of this html. it won't serve up a separate css.

Update:

let's take a look at your relative url.

base Url: www.example.com/ <-- this point to an API gateway, which will invoke a lambda.

relative url: style.css
the browser converts this to absolute url before going to find the resource. 
absolute url: www.example.com/style.css - the request gets routed to API gateway and it doesn't know what to do.

does that make sense?

You want to put the index.php into the lambda. css file into s3. the index.php should know the absolute url of css. You can make the url for the s3 bucket an environment variable in the lambda. so you can update that if you ever need to.

Comment: I used another approach. I uploaded my code to s3 directly and connect with a lambda function. Still same issue. In this scenario, both index.php and style.css are in s3.

Comment: I observed that relative CSS URL throws 403. If I copy the absolute URL from s3 and use then it works fine. Why So?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want another question which falls under the category of this question. My question is how I can run october cms/laravel on lambda easily. I'm just imagining to upload lambda and create api end point for it. Is it possible, if not then whats the other way?

Comment: Unfortunately Lambda isn’t a good option for running a cms. I would recommend you look into EC2s. Better yet, a docker container and Fargate! That way it can scale! Hope that helps.